# Trying to set .html files with htmljinja filetype and get correct indentation

Tags: vim

I have just this configuration below. When I uncomment the last line, I dont get the correct indentation: the lines are put in the first column when I indent.

```
syntax on

autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2

"au BufRead,BufNewFile *.html set filetype=htmljinja
```

I need the htmljinja filetype because my html has twig code (twig's syntax is like htmljinja)

I have vim 7.3.547

Comment: How can I get correct indentation using `gg=G` and htmljinja syntax highlighting in my .html files?

Comment: I would give up now, honestly. Vim is the worst at indenting anything. It always has been and always will be. It's almost as if it's by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime i circumvent vim's indentation capabilities and rather rely on specific indenters/reformatter wherever i can (by the way if anybody is aware of a `tex`/`latex` reformatter please let me know).

As a result the following lines found their way into my `.vimrc`:

```
au FileType c,cpp let &l:equalprg="indent -br -l62 -nce -blf -bbb -i4 -nbfde -nbfda -bad -bap -cli4 -nut"
au FileType perl let &l:equalprg="perltidy"
noremap <leader>i mzgg=G`z
```

A drawback of this approach is that you can't enjoy automatic indentation while writing. Nevertheless I get used to it very fast and I think of it as a very solid and suitable solution to the indentation-problem. Moreover the indented code looks great and i doubt that those fancy IDE's keep up with it.

**Now, what has this got to do with your problem?**

Following my approach i searched for an html-reformatter and found `tidy`. `tidy` seems to be a monster, that not only can pretty-print your html files but also can validate and correct them.

In order to cope with `tidy` you have to write a config file for your indentation purposes. The following one works for me:

`~/.tidyrc_indent`:

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 3
show-warnings: no
show-errors: 0
quiet: yes
indent-cdata: yes
output-html: yes
wrap: 80
```

But make sure to read the man pages of `tidy` because the options seems to be endless.

Now you can add

```
au FileType htmljinja let &equalprg="tidy -config ~/.tidyrc"
```

to your `.vimrc` and start indenting your html file with `gg=G` or a derived mapping that needs less keystrokes.

Please take care as `tidy` like any other reformatter may mess up your code. Therefore you should back up your code regularly (maybe with `git` or something similar). Although i never experienced this by myself wiht `perltidy` and `indent` there are some reports on the internet of angry users that complain about such events.

Comment: where can I find tidy?

Comment: On a debian related system simply run `sudo apt-get install tidy`. The  project's website is `http://tidy.sourceforge.net`.